# What game are these cards from?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image: Drawing of character fom the animé and manga Bleach. From left to right: Ulquiorra Cifer, Byakuya Kuchiki, Ichigo Kurosaki, Gin Ichimaru, Grimmjow Jaegerjaquez]

What game do the cards in the hands of the guy second from the right (Gin Ichimaru) come from, if they do come from from any game?

Comment: (The guys themselves, of course, are from _Bleach_: Ulquiorra, Byakuya, Ichigo, Gin and Grimmjow )

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I knew that much I was looking for fan art when I stumbled upon it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as I can tell they are standard [Tarot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarot) cards. Shown are [Judgement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgement_%28Tarot_card%29) and [The Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tower_%28Tarot_card%29).

While there are games that can be played with them, they are not **from** a specific game.

Comment: In fact, performing a search on the linked wallpaper image ("Bleach Guys"), various websites hosting it which include an image tagging feature have it tagged with "tarot". It's a bit odd, though, considering AFAIK the only tarot cards to appear in _Bleach_ are used by Ugaki and his doll Gessel (in the anime's Bount filler-arc).